# javascript is not working on Safari since high sierra upgrade

Tags: javascript, safari

This javascript works on IE, google and firefox but not Safari since high sierra upgrade; any suggestions?

```
window.open("mailto:" + str);
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: none are showing but when I debug I get the alert to enable Mail and it opens a message; but when I don't debug I don't get the alert